# How to mock/stub Java container in unit testing?

Tags: java, servlets, junit, glassfish, mocking

I have an object that implements `ServletContextListener` which, according to the Java EE servlet spec, is invoked by the servlet container at deployment/startup time via its `contextInitialized(ServletContext)` method.

I am trying to write a unit test that simulates a servlet container starting up and deploying my `ServletContextListener` (so that I can determine if the app is initializing correctly).

Is this possible, and if so, how? Is it container-specific? If so I am using OGS. Looking for code that looks *something* like this:

```
@Test
public void shouldBootstrapAppAtDeployTime() {
    // Given
    GlassFishContainer container = new GlassFishContainer(); // ha!
    MyApp app = mock(MyApp.class); // MyApp implements ServletContextListener

    // When - deploy app to container
    // Causes app.contextInitialized(ServletContext) to be called
    container.deploy(app);

    // Then - verify the method was called with any ServletContext
    mock.verify(app.contextInitialized(Matchers.any());
}
```

This is sloppy pseudo-code with some poorly-implemented Mockito sprinkled in for demo purposes (just to get my intentions across). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can solve this with Arquillian: http://arquillian.org/features/

From the web page:

> Arquillian brings your test to the runtime, giving you access to container resources, meaningful feedback and insight about how the code really works.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is slightly mistaken. What your unit test pseudocode does is testing the container logic that it correctly calls your ServletContextListener - I would trust the container doing that properly.

What I would do is testing your listener class directly, instantiate it, call the contextInitialized() method with a mock ServletContext (I see you're familiar with Mockito, an excellent tool for the job!), and do your assertions if your ServletContextListener did its job as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure if there is such testing framework**. Even if it exists, it will **not be testing in the real environment**(which might be different from the testing environment).

The best way to write this kind of testcases is :

1. Deploy the war using ANT, the server you are using might be providing an MBean or something to deploy the application
2. Your listener might be doing some functionality when contextInitialized() method was invoked.
3. Write a client which makes a request to server and checks if the step 2 was successful or not.